# need help installing emacs rails reloaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

Hi I am trying to install the emacs rails reloaded mode from https://github.com/dima-exe/emacs-rails-reloaded.

As per the directions I have cloned the repo and added the lines to my .emacs file. However it asks for byte compiling by -

> Next bytecompile, press [M-x] and type rails/bytecompile.

However I cant find that function, what do I do ?

Comment: What happens when you try? What error message, if any, do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you should restart Emacs between the steps

> After that add bellow code in your the .emacs file:
>
> (setq load-path (cons (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/rails-reloaded")
>   load-path))
>     (require 'rails-autoload)

and

> Next bytecompile, press [M-x] and type rails/bytecompile.

Also, before restarting, make sure that you have changed `"~/.emacs.d/rails-reloaded"` to the actual path where the file *rails-autoload.el* lives. If you cloned the git repository, that path name should almost certainly end in *emacs-rails-reloaded* (and not just *rails-reloaded*).

If that path is incorrect, Emacs will report an error when it tries to execute `(require 'rails-autoload)`. If it is correct, <kbd>M-x rails/bytecompile</kbd> should work.

Comment: I have set the load-path yet when I run bytecompile, I get numerous warnings about require cl package at runtime. In fact I have also added a line for that in my .emacs yet it does not work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, the issue was I had added wrong "~/.emacs.d/emacs-rails-reloaded" path